# HP ML350 Gen9 drive cage replacement

Tags: hp

I bought HP ML350 G9 L0A11A server. It supports 3.5" HDs but I bought three 2.5" HDs.
Can I replace included LFF cage with SFF cage 726545-B21 ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The chassis on this server model are either SFF (2.5") or LFF (3.5").
You can't mix and match the drive cages.

[image]